# JavaFX runs very very slow on raspberry pi 3b

Tags: java, linux, performance, javafx, debian

I am working on a car dashboard in a screen, more like a normal screen car but with gauges also.

I did one test with Java swing and the performance was ok but I liked more beautiful design (and also to use a gauge library called Medusa gauges) so I shift to javafx.

I made like nothing to fancy, full screen with 4 buttons and 2 gauges of the Medusa library. It took like 30 seconds to start and it was running really really slow.

Any suggestions of anything I can do or I have to come back to swing?

Also are there any other better ways of doing this project like OpenGL or something?

I want the best for the project not the easiest.

- [Raspberry pi 3b](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/)
- Raspi os lite 64bits no desktop (bullseye)
- Using xorg to render (startx command)
- Java 17
- JavaFX 20

Comment: To diagnose performance issues, it is often best to use a profiler. Usually, you can [profile remotely](https://www.baeldung.com/visualvm-jmx-remote).  Whether that is possible with the Raspberry Pi, I do not know.   JavaFX also includes a [pulse logger](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/pull/272) for reporting performance info (I have no advice on how to use it).

Comment: You should post the code for the tiniest app that can demonstrate your slowness.

Comment: Add a link to a page for the OS you are using.

Comment: (1) DIY Raspberry Pi Racecar Dashboard: The Ultimate Guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVn9uYfEQrA) ; Cold Boot To Desktop: 18 secs;
Full Screen Dashboard: 34 secs(include Cold Boot to Desktop)
(2) Pi OS Image: DietPi(https://dietpi.com/)